# How to get all result from MutableLiveData in Android?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

I am using LiveData in my app, and I have a Model and a ViewModel. Here is my Model and ViewModel class:

```js
public class HomeMenuModel {

  String id;
  String title;

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

}
```

```js
public class DashboardViewModel {

  public MutableLiveData < HomeMenuModel > menuList = new MutableLiveData < > ();
  private List<String> idList = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<String> idLists = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();

  public MutableLiveData < HomeMenuModel > setupMenu(Context mCtx) {

    idList.add("homeData");
    idList.add("homeVoiceAndSMS");
    idList.add("homeRoaming");
    idList.add("homeDigital");

    titleList.add(mCtx.getString(R.string.homeData));
    titleList.add(mCtx.getString(R.string.homeVoiceAndSMS));
    titleList.add(mCtx.getString(R.string.homeRoaming));
    titleList.add(mCtx.getString(R.string.homeDigital));

    HomeMenuModel homeMenuModel = new HomeMenuModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < idList.size(); i++) {
      homeMenuModel.setId(idList.get(i));
      homeMenuModel.setTitle(titleList.get(i));
    }

    menuList.setValue(homeMenuModel);
    return menuList;

  }

}
```

I tried to add idList and titleList to setupMenu and return the menuList from the function. I called the setupMenu function in my Fragment, with this code:

```js
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment {

  static final String TAG = "FragmentHome";
  private FragmentHomeBinding mBinding;
  @Inject
  DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel;
  private Context mCtx;

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    View v = mBinding.getRoot();
    mCtx = mBinding.getRoot().getContext();
    initEvent();
    return v;
  }

  private void initEvent() {
    mBinding.setDashboardView(dashboardViewModel);
    dashboardViewModel.setupMenu(mCtx).observe(this, data - > {
      Log.e("menuList", data.getTitle());
    });
  }

  @Override
  public String getTagFragment() {
    return TAG;
  }

}
```

I Log.e the menuList in a HomeFragment, but unfortunately, I only got the last item of the id's or title's returned from observe.

What am I missing here?

Why do I get only the last item of result instead of 4 results created in setupMenu function? How do I get all 4 results?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only update last info for `homeMenuModel`. to get all item you should create `MutableLiveData<ArrayList<HomeMenuModel>>`. Try this

```
    private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<HomeMenuModel>> menuList = new MutableLiveData<ArrayList<HomeMenuModel>>()

    ArrayList<HomeMenuModel> list = new ArrayList<HomeMenuModel>()
    for (int i = 0; i < idList.size(); i++) {
      HomeMenuModel homeMenuModel = new HomeMenuModel();
      homeMenuModel.setId(idList.get(i));
      homeMenuModel.setTitle(titleList.get(i));
      list.add(homeMenuModel)
    }
    menuList.setValue(list);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  If I'm not mistaken, the code you provide in this are written in Kotlin right? I'm not familiar with Kotlin yet, can you kindly provide the code in Java instead? thanks.

Comment: Where is Kotlin?